# Can't add Object to an Array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm having an empty array for my breadcrumb and wanna fill it with every step i take in my category tree.

But as i said in Title, it won't add or to be more precise, it add but won't show!!

it wont show on my template! it wont show on console! only when i `console.log("bread", Array.from(this.breadcrumbs))` it shows in console.

how can i fill my `this.breadcrumbs` with the category obj that i send trough an event!!

my category structure is like this: `{id: 1, title: "Cat1"}`

here is the code of page:

my main problem is that i'm checking if the `breadcrumbs` has length show it, but since i get empty arr even after push, my breadcrumb section just show the `all`.

**Update:**
i removed the if statements in my template, breadcrumb section and i when i click a cat it's title will be shown on breadcrumb but length and array still empty even as trying to display on template!! ( `{{breadcrumb}}` and `{{breadcrumb.length}} are` []`and`0` ).

BTW i'm on Nuxtjs 2.13

```
<template>
<div class="ma-4">
  <!-- Breadcrumb -->
  <div class="d-flex">
    <template v-if="breadcrumbs.length">
      <span role="button" @click.prevent="getAll()">{{lang.all}} > </span>
      <span role="button" v-for="(br, index) in newBreadCrumb" :key="br.id" @click.prevent="goBread(br, index)">{{br.title}} > </span>
      <span>{{breadcrumbs[breadcrumbs.length - 1]}}</span>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <span>{{lang.all}}</span>
    </template>
  </div>
  <!--btn add-->
  <addcatbtn v-if="showBtn" @clicked="addNewCat()" />
  
  <!--cards-->
  <categorylistcard v-for="(category, index) in cmsCat" 
  :key="category.id" 
  :cat="category" 
  :index="index" 
  @addnewsub="addNewCat()"
  />
    
<!-- dialog -->
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class="headline" v-if="editId">{{lang.edit}} </span>
        <span class="headline" v-else>{{lang.addcat}} </span>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container grid-list-md>
            <v-layout wrap>
            
            <v-flex xs12>
                <v-text-field :label="lang.title" outlined v-model="title"></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
            
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn class="text_main_color theme__cta__color px-5" @click="closeDialog()">{{lang.close}}</v-btn>
        <v-btn class="text_main_color theme__btn__s px-5" @click="insertData()">{{lang.save}}</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</div>
</template>

<style>

</style>
<script>
import addcatbtn from '~/components/global/cms/addcatbtn'
const categorylistcard = ()=>import('~/components/' + process.env.SITE_DIRECTION + '/cms/categorylistcard')

export default {
    layout:'cms',
    components:{
      'categorylistcard': categorylistcard,
      'addcatbtn': addcatbtn
    },
    data(){
      return{
        dialog: false,
        editId: 0,
        newId: 0,
        title: null,
        catList: [],
        editIndex: 0,
        parentId: 0,
        editSubCat: false,
        showBtn: true,
        onSubCat: false,
        breadcrumbs: []
      }
    },
    methods:{
      addNewCat(){
        this.dialog = true
        this.title = null
      },
      closeDialog(){
        this.dialog = false
        this.title = null
        this.editId = 0
        this.editIndex = 0
      },
      getAll(){
        this.$fetch()
        this.showBtn = true
        this.onSubCat = false
        this.breadcrumbs = []
      },
      goBread(cat, index){
        this.breadcrumbs.lenght = index
        $nuxt.$emit('gobread',cat)
      },
      async insertData(){
        if(this.notEmpty(this.title)){
          if(this.editId){
            let response = await this.axiosGet(`category/update/${this.editId}/${this.title}`)
            if(this.resOk(response.status)){
              const data = {index: this.editIndex , title: this.title}
              if(this.editSubCat){
                this.updateCmsSubCat(data)
              }else{
                this.updateCmsCat(data)
              }
              $nuxt.$emit('editedcat', {id: this.editId, title: this.title})
              this.closeDialog()
            }
          }else{
            if(this.onSubCat){
              let response = await this.axiosGet(`category/insertsub/${this.newId}/${this.title}`)
              if(this.resOk(response.status)){
                // TODO: must get the id from response!!
                console.log('insertsub')
                const data = {id: this.newId*2 , title: this.title}
                this.addCmsSubCat(data)
                this.closeDialog()
              }
            }else{
              let response = await this.axiosGet(`category/insert/${this.title}`)
              if(this.resOk(response.status)){
                // TODO: must get the id from response!!
                const data = {id: 34 , title: this.title}
                this.addCmsCat(data)
                this.closeDialog()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    async fetch(){
      let response = await this.axiosGet(`categories/admin/0/1`)
      if(this.notEmpty(response.data)){
        this.setCmsCat(response.data.items)
      }
    },
    computed:{
      newBreadCrumb(){
        let x = this.breadcrumbs
        return x.splice(this.breadcrumbs.lenght-1,1)
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.$nuxt.$on('deletecat', (index)=>{
        this.removeCmsCat(index)
      })
      this.$nuxt.$on('editcat', (category, index)=>{
        this.title = category.title
        this.editId = category.id
        this.editIndex = index
        this.dialog = true
      })
      this.$nuxt.$on('setparid', (id)=>{
        this.parentId = id
      })
      this.$nuxt.$on('editsub', ()=>{
        this.editSubCat = true
      })
      this.$nuxt.$on('showsub', (cat)=>{
        this.newId = cat.id
        this.showBtn = !this.showBtn
        this.onSubCat = !this.onSubCat
      })
      this.$nuxt.$on('addbreadcrumb', (category)=>{
        
          this.breadcrumbs.push(category) // category:{id: 1, title: "Cat1"}
          console.log('cat: ')
          console.log(category) // get the obj
          console.log('bread: ')
          console.log(this.breadcrumbs) // get empty array
      })
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am looking at it, just saw this typo doing so `this.breadcrumbs.lenght = index`

Comment: also I can't find where is the `updateCmsCat()` method located at and the code where you actually update the array.

Comment: @djiss on first comment: where is typo!!? i get index from event and change my array length to that index. (for deleting after that index). and those function that you cant find are globally added! `updateCmsCat()` is a mapAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your computed, you are calling `splice`. That mutates the object.  A big no-no in vue is to mutate your state from a computed property.

Try to create a new object and return it, by calling `slice` first:

```
 const copy = x.slice()
 copy.splice(this.breadcrumbs.length-1,1)
 return copy
```

Also, you have a typo `lenght` instead of `length`